# Can I use Azure Active Directory B2C to secure an API contained in a non-B2C directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an API which is hosted within a corporate Azure Active Directory but I want to allow non-corporate users to sign up and use the service. It looks like Azure AD B2C provides this functionality, however I am not sure how or if I can authorise access to the API based on identities created in the B2C directory.  Moving the API to the B2C directory is not an option for me.

I'm also finding the entire concept a little confusing because I never want the users of my site to have the ability to administer my Azure infrastructure, so why would they ever be in the same directory together. That just seems like a security risk, am I missing something?

**Is it possible to access an API hosted in a corporate Azure AD using an identity created in an Azure AD B2C directory?**

Comment: It is the desired behavior of B2C tenants that the tenant contains no other resource than the directory itself. So the actuall AppService will always be hosted in a different directory. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this can be achieved by using the Advanced option under Authentication/Authorisation within the Azure Portal for the API you wish to secure and the steps are detailed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-configure-with-advanced-settings

Comment: You will not probably not be able to get your UserJourney (Password reset etc) set up this way. If you do, please let me know :-)

Comment: Yeah, I am now looking at using Auth0 instead.  I'm sure I can get everything working in Azure and that would be my preference but the documentation is terrible compared with Auth0